# Starship areas described but never shown

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I was thinking about something slightly related to this (possible another question later but it might be regarded as a duplicate)

I do not have any specifics tech-wise in this but the question is simple: Are any starship areas mentioned by crew members that we never get to see ?

Either in that episode or a previous / future one . I am trying to stick to TNG here simply as the sets were more erm 'expansive' compared to the original series.

Obviously exclude a mention of a certain corridor section ID or a certain Jeffries tube :D It is specific named locations that I am interested in that are part of the Enterprise itself.

Comment: Loads and loads. Cetacean Ops is the obvious

Comment: We never see the giant duck, or the aeroplane; https://i.imgur.com/gm379NY.jpg

Comment: But was the duck or plane mentioned thought . Hence why I made no reference to either toilet bathroom facilities or indeed the infamous Hamster Wheel :)

Comment: If someone wants to post as an answer just say three or so areas on the Enterprise  mentioned but never ever shown ( no need to reference the episodes as that is asking far too much ) I will likely mark this answered.

Comment: **ENGINEER:** *The quarantine seal is getting weaker.... it's locked three people in a turbolift and two more in **the programmers' rest room.*** - TNG: Home Soil

Comment: There is one [REALLY IMPORTANT AREA](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bowling_alley) on the original TOS Enterprise that fits the bill!

Comment: @Valorum Obviously, if programmers use it, nobody else will want to....

Comment: There is probably a joke about cookies (both browser and food types) that could be added about the coders rest area but hmmm. On topic am happy as mentioned to accept answer with just a few examples, more so if they are referenced on more than one occasion. Does not need to be the same episode either. ;)

Comment: Not sure if the Captain’s Yacht was ever actually mentioned on screen.

Comment: "Stellar cartography" was often spoken of but not see on screen until the film "Generations".